# UINavigationController not working under ARC in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.3

I have created a **new project "Empty Application" template in Xcode 4.3**, it is having only two classes `AppDelegate.h` & .m

**I checked with ARC to use automatic reference count while creating the app.**

I added two *new files "RootViewController" & "NewProjectViewControllers".*

I implemented code to set **navigation controller as follows** in `AppDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
      // Override point for customization after application launch.

      rootViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
      UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
      [self.window addSubview:navigation.view];

      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      return YES;
}
```

and in hte home view (Root view controller) implemented as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      [super viewDidLoad];

      self.title = @"Projects";
      UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
      [navigationBar setTintColor:   [UIColor colorWithRed:10/255.0f green:21/255.0f blue:51/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];     

      //To set the customised bar item
      UIButton *rightBarBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [rightBarBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_new.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      rightBarBtn.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0);
      [rightBarBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addProject)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      UIBarButtonItem* rightBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBarBtn];
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem;

      // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void) addProject
{
      NewProjViewController *editProject = [[NewProjViewController alloc] init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:editProject animated:YES];

      NSLog(@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
```

But since i used ***`ARC`*** the navigation may dealoc immediately and it doesn't work, *All the actions in method works except push to the next view*

**if i do same thing with out ARC it works fine**

How to resolve this issue..? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Your `appdelegate` `appdidfinishlaunching` method, you have not set

`self.window.rootviewcontroller` to `navigationController`. In fact you did not set any `rootViewController` to `Window`. Thats why it is not being shown. Please set it before you start to see your `ViewController` on the screen.

---

The `UIWindow rootViewController` property is new with **iOS4**.

The older technique was to use `addSubview`.

The new, recommended technique is to set `rootViewController`.

Comment: [self.window.rootViewController setView:navigation.view];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NewProjViewController *editProject = [[NewProjViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewProjViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:editProject animated:YES];
    [editProject release];
```

Comment: Sorry i alrady used ARC then y do we need to use Release {exception}